# I'm experiencing problem with timestamps in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to make an app similar to Quote of the day. Here I want to display one quote a day. Like quote1 on day1, quote2 on day2 and so on. I've written code like this:

```
var index = 0
func displayQuote() {
        
        let newTimestamp = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        
        let storedTimestamp = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lastQuoteTimestamp") as? Date
        if storedTimestamp == nil || newTimestamp.timeIntervalSince(storedTimestamp!) / (60 * 60) >= 24 {
            textView.text = quotes[index]
            index += 1
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newTimestamp, forKey: "lastQuoteTimestamp")   
        }  
    }
```

The issues are:

1. When I tested the line (let newTimestamp = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())), in Playground, it gave me local date at 12PM. But when I included it in the project it gives me time as per UTC. How to get the local time instead of UTC in my project code.
2. The index never increments, so same quote appears everyday.
3. When first launched quotes[0] display. But at second run there is a blank screen because this line (UserDefaults.standard.set(newTimestamp, forKey: "lastQuoteTimestamp") ) updates the newTimestamp as lastQuoteTimestamp. When I comment out that line the quote shows at subsequent runs. So how to update the timestamp that the same quote displays through out the day and next quote shows the subsequent day.

I'm unable to figure out the bugs though I tried various ways.

I call the displayQuote() in viewDidLoad().

Thank you.

Comment: `Calendar.calendar.timeZone = .current` will give you the current timezone for Calendar.current. As for the other part, the logic of your if is not right: you increment the `index` but don't use the new value, and don't store it anywhere, so of course you will get the same quote on every app run. Also you only display quote inside that if, so repettive display of the same quote on the same day won't happen. So increment the index inside `if`, while `textView.text = quotes[index]` should be moved under if (to run in all cases). And save index into user defaults

Comment: Calender.calender.timeZone = .current does not work.